# MySQL WorkBench 8.0 Keeps Crashing MacOS Ventura 13.1

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am taking a data analytics and management course for my graduate program. We started doing simple lines of code today like create a table, select, and use functions. However, every-time I go to execute the `select * from` it crashes the program.

I have restarted my computer multiple times. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: why not make a bug report to oracle?

Comment: So you actually get Workbench to open? I don't - crashes immediately. Are you able to use your database/tables from the command line: i.e. /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot to start a session; then use test; (or whatever your database is); then select * from your_table;

Comment: Also, what version of MySQL? When I downloaded the MySQL 8.0.32 bundle there was no mention of the required level of MySQL. Will upgrade if required.

Comment: I suggest you go to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109671 and click the "Affects Me" button (you need a login to do that).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and played around with the version of my SQL workbench. Assuming you're using SQL Workbench 8.0.32, try using SQL Workbench 8.0.31 which is what solved the issue for me.

Comment: I also have a crashing issue after upgrading to MacOS Sonoma 14.0. The issue is resolved by upgrading the SQL Workbench version to 8.0.34.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mac Os Ventura 13.2.1 please follow these steps, I fixed my problem:

1. Install the last version of MySQL Community Server from this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/macos-installation-pkg.html
2. Install Python 2.7.11 via the official pkg installer here (https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/)
3. Install MySQL WorkBench version 8.0.19 from the archive https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

And do not forget to allow privacy and security in the mac os settings.